# Aborting nested fetch requests when component is unmounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

The following function, when consumed, fetches and returns an array of up to 50 comments of a single post. It first fetches a single post by ID, and this post object has an array of comments ID's, which it will fetch.

My goal is to early abort this task in my React class component using `componentWillUnmount`, by calling `abort` on the signal on the class instance. The signal is passed as `abortSignal`.

The question is, I have a case of nested fetch requests. How should I approach this so I can make sure any on-going fetch requests are aborted when the component is unmounting? As I seee it, passing the signal to the outer fetch won't suffice if this stage was already completed. Should I create another signal inside of this function, and pass to to individual fetch?

```
const fetchComments = async (type, abortSignal) => {
    const res = await fetch(endpoints[`${type}Stories`]);
    const post = await res.json();
    return Promise.all(post.slice(0, 50).map(async id => {
        const url = endpoints.singleStory.replace('[id]', id);
        const comment = await fetch(url);
        return comment.json();
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason you can't reuse the `abortSignal` across all the `fetch` calls. You probably also want to check its `aborted` flag after `await`ing so you bail proactively:

```
const fetchComments = async (type, signal) => {
    const res = await fetch(endpoints[`${type}Stories`], {signal});
    if (signal.aborted) {
        return; // Or whatever
    }
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
    }
    const post = await res.json();
    if (signal.aborted) {
        return; // Or whatever
    }
    return Promise.all(post.slice(0, 50).map(async id => {
        // Probably not much point to checking `signal.aborted` here, you *just* checked it above
        const url = endpoints.singleStory.replace('[id]', id);
        const comment = await fetch(url, {signal});
        if (!comment.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + comment.status);
        }
        return comment.json();
    }));
}
```

Two notes on that:

1. I changed `abortSignal` to `signal` so I could use shorthand property notation when passing it to `fetch`, because I'm lazy. :-)
2. Your code is falling prey to [the `fetch` footgun](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) — you need to check for HTTP success, it only rejects on *network* error, not HTTP error. I've inserted checks above.

---

**Note:** If you can modify the API, I'd strongly recommend making it possible to ask for the 50 comments as part of the initial `fetch`, or at least to be able to ask for a batch of comments, rather than loading each comment individually with its own HTTP request (although HTTP/2 helps a lot).

Comment: The API is not mine so unfortunately I cannot modify it.
I did not know you could re-use the signal across multiple fetches to abort all at once, that's interesting. Thank you for the insightful response :)